# Inconsistent Behavior in MS Word When Deleting Words

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2019

I have a weird problem in MS Word, that start's to annoy me, as I do more and more writing. I use the command `Ctrl + Backspace` very often to delete words, especially when I have a typo in the last word, I just delete it completely.

However, sometimes when I do this, it delete the word **and** the space before that word. It would be okay if it would do that every time, but this is only during maybe 50 % of the time. At other times it deletes just the word, so that there is still a space behind the preceding word.

If you write really fast and a lot, this can get annoying, as you never know whether you have to retype a space or not.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I work with MS Word 2019 Professional Plus on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the default behaviour by switching off this option: `Word options > Advanced > Cut, Copy and Paste > Use smart cut and paste > Settings > Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically`.

When it is switched off, you will have two common behaviours to deal with:

- If there is no space immediately after the cursor,
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the word and leaves the
  space before it.
- If there is a space immediately after the cursor,
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the word as well as the
  space before it.